# Allowing user Re-size durandal dialog box

Tags: durandal-2.0

I have a durandal dialog box, i want user to be able to increase or decrease the size of the box . Please note that i am not asking for adjusting the width automatically depending on the contents inside the box. I am actually asking how i can allow user to hover the mouse over any size of the dialog and increase / decrease the size.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [resize CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

```
resize: none
resize: both
resize: horizontal
resize: vertical

resize: inherit
```

for example:

```
.modal{
  resize: none; /* disables resizability */
}
```